# Unable to align tableGrob with barplot (ggplot2) - would like dates in table to align with dates on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, patchwork

So, I have made this barplot of categories by date and I want to put a table of the data below it.  I'm able to assemble it but I can't get the table to align.  It could be anything in my code that's the issue.  I was mainly fooling around with patchwork but was trying grid.arrange before that.  I would appreciate any help as I am not very familiar with either gridExtra or patchwork.

Here's the data and the code:

```
SNcats <- structure(list(spec.date = c("2022-01", "2022-01", "2022-01", 
"2022-02", "2022-02", "2022-02", "2022-03", "2022-03", "2022-03", 
"2022-04", "2022-04", "2022-04", "2022-05", "2022-05", "2022-05", 
"2022-06", "2022-06", "2022-06", "2022-07", "2022-07", "2022-07", 
"2022-08", "2022-08", "2022-08", "2022-09", "2022-09", "2022-09", 
"2022-10", "2022-10", "2022-10", "2022-11", "2022-11", "2022-11", 
"2022-12", "2022-12", "2022-12", "2023-01", "2023-01", "2023-01"
), Prevalence = c(35.7532730691516, 51.6020332612438, 87.3553063302596, 
39.8444277893643, 48.2160832971785, 88.0605110865005, 37.8209796975328, 
52.0475030126012, 89.8684827108602, 38.5822017341404, 46.8328075784517, 
85.415009306803, 37.5983114267099, 49.2418346993315, 86.8401461257731, 
37.073216269802, 50.973491711575, 88.0467079815322, 37.4924651917319, 
48.2141737283447, 85.7066389192143, 37.1730646315648, 50.507713438577, 
87.6807780703307, 34.011831202632, 54.668835496198, 88.6806667081123, 
33.4879698539608, 57.2879814032989, 90.7759512541417, 34.6890742481581, 
57.8203887753151, 92.5094630233588, 37.0324544253768, 54.7515011379788, 
91.783955355063, 36.4346779568341, 52.4230523876185, 88.8577303442384
), LL = c(31.0036784955892, 46.6865137568222, 84.0294744708075, 
35.8934911175723, 44.2294678836092, 85.5201746651143, 32.5918045075412, 
46.7021252787722, 86.6574439277593, 35.7332321084506, 43.9378408519578, 
83.2690129542333, 34.8236562801895, 46.4112667974695, 84.8490432647019, 
34.1589303783171, 47.9808527735242, 86.1062268727187, 35.170825504927, 
45.8461086423908, 83.8557052884791, 35.0257696395504, 48.2978225201125, 
86.1304138927419, 32.0510320212288, 52.6197412698121, 87.4441418189029, 
31.7620042685515, 55.4799317423969, 89.7021275089891, 32.9350706471155, 
56.001650789056, 91.5045773434199, 34.7511549769303, 52.4364225437364, 
90.6046115548134, 34.5985811363114, 50.5172303158065, 87.6570267772486
), UL = c(40.5028676427141, 56.5175527656655, 90.6811381897116, 
43.7953644611564, 52.2026987107478, 90.6008475078866, 43.0501548875245, 
57.3928807464302, 93.0795214939611, 41.4311713598303, 49.7277743049456, 
87.5610056593728, 40.3729665732303, 52.0724026011934, 88.8312489868442, 
39.9875021612869, 53.9661306496258, 89.9871890903457, 39.8141048785368, 
50.5822388142986, 87.5575725499494, 39.3203596235792, 52.7176043570414, 
89.2311422479195, 35.9726303840352, 56.7179297225839, 89.9171915973217, 
35.2139354393702, 59.096031064201, 91.8497749992943, 36.4430778492006, 
59.6391267615742, 93.5143487032977, 39.3137538738233, 57.0665797322211, 
92.9632991553127, 38.2707747773567, 54.3288744594304, 90.0584339112283
), SN.cat = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("S+", 
"S+N-", "S+N+"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), class = "data.frame")



SNcats.w <- structure(list(SN.cat = c("S+", "S+N+", "S+N-"), `2022-01` = c("87.4 (84 - 90.7)", 
"51.6 (46.7 - 56.5)", "35.8 (31 - 40.5)"), `2022-02` = c("88.1 (85.5 - 90.6)", 
"48.2 (44.2 - 52.2)", "39.8 (35.9 - 43.8)"), `2022-03` = c("89.9 (86.7 - 93.1)", 
"52 (46.7 - 57.4)", "37.8 (32.6 - 43.1)"), `2022-04` = c("85.4 (83.3 - 87.6)", 
"46.8 (43.9 - 49.7)", "38.6 (35.7 - 41.4)"), `2022-05` = c("86.8 (84.8 - 88.8)", 
"49.2 (46.4 - 52.1)", "37.6 (34.8 - 40.4)"), `2022-06` = c("88 (86.1 - 90)", 
"51 (48 - 54)", "37.1 (34.2 - 40)"), `2022-07` = c("85.7 (83.9 - 87.6)", 
"48.2 (45.8 - 50.6)", "37.5 (35.2 - 39.8)"), `2022-08` = c("87.7 (86.1 - 89.2)", 
"50.5 (48.3 - 52.7)", "37.2 (35 - 39.3)"), `2022-09` = c("88.7 (87.4 - 89.9)", 
"54.7 (52.6 - 56.7)", "34 (32.1 - 36)"), `2022-10` = c("90.8 (89.7 - 91.8)", 
"57.3 (55.5 - 59.1)", "33.5 (31.8 - 35.2)"), `2022-11` = c("92.5 (91.5 - 93.5)", 
"57.8 (56 - 59.6)", "34.7 (32.9 - 36.4)"), `2022-12` = c("91.8 (90.6 - 93)", 
"54.8 (52.4 - 57.1)", "37 (34.8 - 39.3)"), `2023-01` = c("88.9 (87.7 - 90.1)", 
"52.4 (50.5 - 54.3)", "36.4 (34.6 - 38.3)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

g0 <- ggplot(SNcats, aes(x=spec.date, y=Prevalence, color=SN.cat, fill=SN.cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(0.85), width=0.8) +
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=spec.date, ymin=LL, ymax=UL, color="black"),
                 position=position_dodge(0.85), 
                 width=0.3) +   
  geom_bar_pattern(aes(pattern=SN.cat, fill=SN.cat, color=SN.cat),
                              position=position_dodge(0.85),
                              stat="identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(x="Date")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("S+"= "steelblue4", "S+N-"="darkorange", "S+N+"="springgreen4"), aesthetics=c("color", "fill")) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c(rep(c('stripe', 'circle', 'crosshatch'),1))) 

library(gridExtra)

tt <- ttheme_default(
  base_size = 9,
  padding = unit(c(2, 4), "mm"),
  # Alternate the row fill colours
  core = list(fg_params=list(hjust = 1, x=1),
              bg_params=list(fill=c("white", "white"))),
  
  # Change column header to white text and red background
  colhead = list(fg_params=list(col="black"),
                 bg_params=list(fill="white")))

tbl <- tableGrob(SNcats.w, rows=NULL, theme=tt)

grid.arrange(g0, tbl, nrow=2, heights=c(1,0.5))

library(patchwork)

layout <- c(
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 8, r = 5),
  area(t = 9, l = 1, b = 10, r = 5))  # r = 4 shoves it off the left side

p1 <- g0 + tbl + plot_layout(design=layout) 

p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table plot needs to have the same x axis scale as your main plot. I would use only your first dataframe to generate both plots here.

Your main plot is problematic. Using dodged bars here is unnecessary, makes it harder to see the patterns in the data, and distorts the apparent time group measurements were taken. The patterns in the bars don't add anything to the information shown and seem to be purely for decoration, yet they make everything look cluttered and less aesthetically appealing. I would probably use error bars and ribbons here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- SNcats %>%
  mutate(spec.date = lubridate::ym(spec.date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(spec.date, Prevalence, ymin = LL, ymax = UL)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(color = SN.cat, fill = after_scale(alpha(color, 0.1))),
              linetype = 0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(color = SN.cat), width = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(color = SN.cat)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_date(NULL, date_breaks = "month", date_labels = "%Y-%m") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

 p2 <- SNcats %>%
  mutate(spec.date = lubridate::ym(spec.date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(spec.date, SN.cat)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Prevalence, 1), "\n",
                               " (", round(LL, 1),  " - ", 
                               round(UL, 1), ")")), size = 2.5) +
  scale_x_date(NULL, date_breaks = "month", date_labels = "%Y-%m",
               position = "top") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text())
 
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really have a choice with using the bars.  That was a request to match other graphs by the data owner. I do agree with your assessment of it, however. I would prefer linegraph with ribbon. I will try the other parts of your solution for my barplot and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: The part where you used the original data to feed into geom_text was the perfect solution!  I still do agree with use that barplots and patterns aren't a good choice.  And the data owner agreed when I originally pointed that out but they have done them this way and don't want to redo all the previous work. So...  Anyway, thank you!  Perfect.